# Scipt for selecting only the active collections

Tags: scripting

can you guys tell me how to do this but only selecting "active" collections not all collections

```
import bpy

def rename_objects():
    # Get all collections in the scene
    collections = bpy.context.scene.collection.children

    # Iterate through each collection
    for collection in collections:
        # Starting number for numbering
        count = 0

        # Iterate through each object in the collection
        for obj in collection.objects:
            # Rename the object with the collection name and sequential number
            obj.name = f"{collection.name}{count}" if count > 0 else f"{collection.name}"
            count += 1

#Call the function to rename objects
rename_objects()
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was flawed – the script was renaming only children of the first level collections

*thanks to @Gorgious for noticing that.

Here is the fixed script, which renames objects in ALL active collections
(no matter how deeply are they located in the collection hierarchy)

HERE :

---

```
import bpy



active_collections = []

all_collections = bpy.data.collections

scene_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection

collections_to_process = [scene_collection]




def find_active():
##
            
    for col in collections_to_process:
                 
        for sub_collection in col.children:    
             
            collections_to_process.append(sub_collection)
            
                
            if not sub_collection.exclude:
                
                active_collections.append(sub_collection.name)
                
                     
                                  
        collections_to_process.remove(col)
             
             
                     
    if collections_to_process:
        
        find_active()        
##          
        


def rename_objects():              
## 

    for collection in all_collections:
        
        if not collection.name in active_collections:
            
            continue
        
        
        for i in range( len(collection.objects)):
            
            new_name = collection.name
            
            if i > 0:
                
                new_name += f' {i}'
                
                
            object = collection.objects[i]
        
            object.name = new_name
##



find_active()

rename_objects()
```